# How to keep fixed width for table data, NOT EQUAL

Tags: css, html-table

I have table with the `<td>` width set as auto (i.e. Not given), after clicking the edit icon I changed the content for `<td>` from "text" to "input box" and as you can see the image below, all the input boxes change the alignment of table, also because of which the whole table looks disturbed as soon as the user clicks it.

It's just how to keep the `td's` as same width before with setting the width individually, also keeping it responsive on screen size

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to restrict / adjust the size of the corresponding `th` element.

```css
th:first-child {
  width: 100px;
}

th:nth-child(2) {
  width: 300px;
}

th:nth-child(3) {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th >First</th>
      <th >Last</th>
      <th >@username</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't get the use for `scope="col"`, but at the end as i mentioned, I assume I'll have to give them width individually

Comment: @ShubhamSinghvi removed scope="col". Yes, that is the only way. If there are multiple columns that have the same width, you can select them together.